# Can't interpret SPSS Error Message in MATRIX code

Tags: spss

A program to run a Schmid-Leiman transformation using SPSS's Matrix language was published in 2005 by Woolf & Preising in Behavior Research Methods volume 37, pages 48 to 58). It is probably not important for you to know what a Schmid-Leiman transformation is, but I'll explain in comments if you feel it is necessary.

In modifying the program for my own data, I'm getting an error I can't figure out:

> Error # 12302 in column 12.  Text: , 
>   Syntax error. 
>   Execution of this command stops. 
>   Error in RIGHT HAND SIDE of COMPUTE command.
>
> The MATRIX statement skipped.

Here is the beginning of the code. The error is showing as coming in Line 6:

```
* Encoding: UTF-8. 
* Schmid-Leiman Solution for 2 level higher-order Factor analysis. 
Matrix. 
* ENTER YOUR SPECIFICATIONS HERE. 
* Enter first-order pattern matrix. 
Compute F1={.461, .253, -.058, -.069; 
.241, .600, .143, .033; 
.582, .047, -.077, -.125; 
.327, .297, -.120, -.166; 
.176, .448, -.240, -.099; 
.680, .069, -.036, -.138; 
.415, .228, -.091, -.153;
            .
            .
            .
.390, .205, .002, -.098; 
.164, .369, -.170, -.047 
 }.
```

As shown above, the text generating the error is shown as a comma (,), but the actual text (following the COMPUTE statement) in column 12 is an open bracket ({). So I have no idea what is going on. Can someone help?

For reference, the original code as proposed by Woolf & Preising (2005) is found [here](https://static-content.springer.com/esm/art%3A10.3758%2FBF03206397/MediaObject/13428_2011_BF03206397_MOESM1_ESM.zip);

The Woolf & Preising article is found [here](https://link.springer.com/article/10.3758/BF03206397)

PS: The sample program given in the link above does run on my copy of SPSS. Here's the beginning of that code:

```
    * Schmid-Leiman Solution for 2 level higher-order Factor analysis. 
    Matrix. 
    * ENTER YOUR SPECIFICATIONS HERE. 
    * Enter first-order pattern matrix. 
    Compute F1={0.099, 0.5647,  -0.1521; 
                0.0124, 0.9419,  -0.1535; 
               -0.1501, 0.6177, 0.4218; 
                0.7441, -0.0882, 0.1425; 
                0.6241, 0.2793, -0.1137; 
                0.8693, -0.0331, 0.0289; 
               -0.0154, -0.2706, 0.6262; 
               -0.0914,  0.0995, 0.7216; 
                0.1502, 0.0835, 0.398}.
```

Comment: How can you tell the error is from line 6? I copied your code sample and ran it here with no problem, so maybe the error is in a different line not included in your sample.

Comment: The first error shows up in the syntax editor as line 6. It could be from a later line, but it's a very long program, so I didn't want to include the whole thing. I could edit to add at least the whole matrix block.

Comment: OK I think line 6 may refer to the line where the problematic command begins - that would be `Compute F1=`, but the actual problem must occur further down the syntax - within that command. In order to debug this I'd try to run only this command, and then try deleting some lines of the command until the problem disappears so you can tell which line is the problematic one.